# How to import an SQL database file

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm following [this](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) recommended guide to create a SQLite database with pre-loaded data; however I cannot understand how to produce the required database file (.db).

I have used the software "DB Browser for SQLite" to write up my database, but can only seem to save the file as the commands to create a database (`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` etc.).

How do I save my file into the required .db format?

[This](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/android-sqlite3-file-is-encrypted-or-is-not-a-database) website's solution is why I think my file is in the wrong format.

For context, the error I am experiencing is as follows:

```
09-02 23:47:58.681 19704-19704/company.app W/SQLiteAssetHelper: copying database from assets...
09-02 23:47:58.682 19704-19704/company.app W/SQLiteAssetHelper: database copy complete
09-02 23:47:58.684 19704-19704/company.app E/SQLiteLog: (26) file is encrypted or is not a database
09-02 23:47:58.684 19704-19704/company.app E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler: Corruption reported by sqlite on database: /data/user/0/company.app /databases/app .db
09-02 23:47:58.684 19704-19704/company.app E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler: deleting the database file: /data/user/0/company.app /databases/app .db
09-02 23:47:58.686 19704-19704/company.app E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 32504 of [bda77dda96]
09-02 23:47:58.686 19704-19704/company.app E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:32504: (2) open(/data/user/0/company.app /databases/app .db) - 
09-02 23:47:58.687 19704-19704/company.app E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/company.app /databases/app .db'.
                                                                        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:808)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:796)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:671)
                                                                            at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.returnDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:408)
                                                                            at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:401)
                                                                            at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:176)
                                                                            at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:254)
                                                                            at company.app .MyDatabase.randomiseItBro(MyDatabase.java:33)
                                                                            at company.app .MainActivity.randomise(MainActivity.java:55)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4695)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22285)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
09-02 23:47:58.688 19704-19704/company.app W/SQLiteAssetHelper: could not open database app .db - unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
09-02 23:47:58.689 19704-19704/company.app D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-02 23:47:58.689 19704-19704/company.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: company.app , PID: 19704
                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                            at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4700)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22285)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4695)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612) 
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22285) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757) 
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getVersion()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:178)
                                                                            at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:254)
                                                                            at company.app .MyDatabase.randomiseItBro(MyDatabase.java:33)
                                                                            at company.app .MainActivity.randomise(MainActivity.java:55)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4695) 
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612) 
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22285) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the "New Database" toolbar button, you create a SQLite database file. When you create tables and stuff, then click the "Write Changes" toolbar button, you update that database file. Once you have the database file the way that you want, that is the file that you include in your `assets/` for use by `SQLiteAssetHelper`.

The Linux edition of DB Browser for SQLite does not apply a file extension by default to the file. You will want to add the `.db` yourself when creating the database file, or rename it after you create it.

Comment: I have tried this, but continue to get errors. My research has led me to believe my database file is in the wrong format; are you saying the file is meant to be in the form `CREATE TABLE` etc?

Comment: @TomJames: No. If you follow the instructions that I outlined, you get a SQLite database file, able to be used by SQLite clients besides DB Browser for SQLite (e.g., `sqlite3` command-line tool). With regards to your stack trace, fully uninstall the app, then try reinstalling and running it. Also, FWIW, your `applicationId` and database filename seem to have spaces in them, though my guess is that this is an artifact of how you posted the material to your question.

Comment: I understand now, you've solved my question. Thanks for being patient; and yes, that was just me hastily pasting over the application and company names.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file just like a myfunc.js file or index.html but this one is mydb.sql with the codes. Regular word file ex:

`CREATE DATABASE activedb;
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    column1 datatype,
    column2 datatype,
    column3 datatype,
   ....
);`

then you can use `database_name < mydb.sql`
I think that is what you are trying to do. I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking care correctly in your application to transfer the database from the assets to your database directory, then you are probably missing one of the following two requirements:

1. the primary key needs to be named `_id`
2. the database needs one specific table that you need to craete: `CREATE TABLE android_metadata (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, locale TEXT)`